# Display time of day when a button is pressed ios

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to display time of day (for example, `14:02`) and display it in a `UILable`.

Here's my code to retrieve system time:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond], from: date)
 _ = components.hour
```

I can't figure out how to feed it to the label.

```
mylable.text = "???"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DateFormatter` instead of `DateComponents` to get `Date` or `Time` in specific format.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let time = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
mylable.text = time
```

Comment: @AntonPlatonov Welcome mate :)

Comment: There is one more small question. I can't integrate it in the button function as it works only in super.ViewDidLoad. I tried to create a boolean and use if-statement in super.ViewDidLoad... no use...UPD: I put the whole block of code in the button funs and it worked. Thanks again

Comment: @AntonPlatonov Edit your question with your code that is not working.

Comment: UPD: I put the whole block of code in the button func and it works. Thanks again